# Java rounding floats to x decimal places incorrect

Tags: java, rounding

My current method of rounding to x decimal places:

```
public static float roundInc(float value, float increment) {
    float inc = 1f / increment;
    return Math.round(value * inc) / inc;
}
```

Which works fine for certain numbers, but seems to break, and I can't seem to figure this out.

I pass through the value 2.109375
Output of the function returns 2.11
Then I add that to 5.0 (is also a float, stored in a float array (float[])), and for some bizarre reason, adding the 2.11 + 5.0 returns 7.1099997...

Can someone explain this? Cause as far as I can see, after printing the two 2.11, and 5.0, showing those two exact values, then added together breaks everything...

Comment: For other ways to round a floating point number in Java, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java?rq=1

Comment: `float`s are the wrong type for this.  Only `BigDecimal` will do this correctly.

Comment: Using BigDecimal's still causes the same problem, as do double's. Also found Python has the same problem even just printing "2.11 + 5.0"

Comment: Everyone please go read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Thanks for that @JimGarrison, definitely clears a lot up on the matter.

Comment: @SolarEntropy you must be a fast reader. There's enough detail there to keep someone busy for at least an hour :-)

Comment: @JimGarrison I got the gist of it after a quick skim, also Thilo marked this as a duplicate, and the one it was marked a dupe of also iterated similar points.